# Internal angle bevel is not working

Tags: modeling

I would like to make a corner like the image.

But bevel on the side of the internal angle I made, doesn't change anything.

So What should I do...

Is there a way other than bevel or Is my modeling structure bad?

Blender 3.0 Alpha

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the inner face, it prevents to do any bevel:

[image]

Comment: Ohhh It work!!! Thank you so much!!! Your save my day!